# What is the sequence for Form and other object creation in Lazarus

Tags: freepascal, lazarus

I have a simple program with two forms, a main form and a settings form. Obviously the settings form allows the user to change settings. I have a settings unit whose initialization section reads settings from a file.

When the program is first installed and started up for the first time, the settings will be empty and if so I want to show the settings form. The question is where to put the check and invoking code.

My Application.lpr contains

```
begin
  RequireDerivedFormResource := True;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.CreateForm(TSettingsForm, SettingsForm);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

My Settings unit is roughly like this

```
uses
  Classes, SysUtils, INIFiles;

type
  TSettings = class
    public
      procedure LoadFromFile();
      procedure SaveToFile();
    ...
    end;

var
  Settings: TSettings;

implementation

{ TSettings }

...

initialization
  Settings := TSettings.Create;
  Settings.LoadFromFile();

finalization
  Settings.SaveToFile();
  FreeAndNil(Settings);

end.
```

If I do this check for empty settings in MainForm.FormCreate, I can't show the Settings Form because it hasn't been created yet.

I don't see how I could do it in Application.lpr as there isn't an obvious variable there to refer to the SettingsForm instance. Anyway it doesn't feel right to put it there.

- Can I do this check in SettingsForm.FormCreate assuming that this is only called *after* SettingsForm is fully initialized and ready to be shown? Can you call `Show()` in `FormCreate()`?
- I'm not sure when exactly my Settings type gets instantiated.
- Are there any ideas, guidelines design-patterns or other material I could use to determine where to put my check for empty settings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The forms are created in the order that, well, they are created in your program file. The visible forms won't be shown until Application.Run.

There's no reason at all why you cannot drive the "first run" logic from the program file. For example, you might write:

```
begin
  RequireDerivedFormResource := True;
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
  Application.CreateForm(TSettingsForm, SettingsForm);
  if SettingsForm.FirstTime then
    SettingsForm.ShowModal;
  Application.Run;
end.
```

Personally I would avoid having global variables holding form instances. It's reasonable for the main form which is always in existence. But for other forms, I'd just create them on demand. If you switched to that approach then you could do the first time settings UI from the main form constructor.

---

An aside. Your settings finalization block is risky. If the Settings instance creation fails then your finalization block will result in an AV. You should write:

```
finalization
  if Assigned(Settings) then
    Settings.SaveToFile();
  FreeAndNil(Settings);
```

Comment: I added `If Settings.AreIncomplete then SettingsForm.Show;` but it throws an exception *"ShowModal for SettingsForm impossible because already visible (hint for designer forms: set visible property to false)"* (note: I do have `SettingsForm.Visible` set to `false` in the IDE). `SettingsForm.Show` (i.e nonmodal) runs but isn't useful as I need for the program to wait for settings to be complete.

Comment: That makes little sense to me. If Visible is False, why does the runtime tell you that the form is visible. As I said in my answer, avoiding global variables, and pre-created forms would simply avoid all such issues.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a pretty simple list of the sequence of the Delphi form creation.**

Now, if I'm not mistaking, your forms are created in the sequence they are listed in your .dpr file (see project->view source), and the first form listed there will be your main form.

Edit:

---

*ACTION*

Create -> Show -> Paint -> Activate -> ReSize -> Paint -> Close query -> Close -> Deactivate -> Hide -> Destroy

---

*EVENT*

OnCreate -> OnShow -> OnPaint -> OnActivate -> OnResize -> OnPaint -> OnCloseQuery -> OnClose -> OnDeactivate -> OnHide -> OnDestroy

(Quoted from [here](http://delphi.about.com/cs/adptips1999/a/bltip0499_5.htm))